# Can't get value from get_theme_mod using WP_Customize_Image_Cropped_Control

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can't output value from WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control.

I can't understand what I am doing wrong, my image picking and saving fine in customizer, but can't output this image. Here is my code for customizer:

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting('mobile_logo', array(
        'transport' => 'postMessage',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'absint'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'mobile_logo', array(
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Mobile Logo', 'my_theme' ),
        'height' => 80,
        'width' => 120,
        'flex-height' => true,
        'flex-width' => true,
        'settings' => 'mobile_logo',
        'section' => 'title_tagline',
    )));
```

My code for output:

```
<?php
    $mobile_logo = get_theme_mod( '_mobile_logo' );
?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($mobile_logo); ?>">
```

I tried var_dump $mobile_logo and all I get is string(0) "".

Can you help me, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an answer, I should use wp_get_attachment_image_url().
So the answer is:

```
<?php
    $mobile_logo = get_theme_mod( 'mobile_logo' );
?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_image_url($mobile_logo)); ?>">
```